# How to manage a collection of collections?

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to manage a collection of collections. See example code below:

```
function Collection() {
    this.items = []; //Contains items, which have a date associated with them
}
Collection.prototype.doSomethingOnItems = function(){};

function SuperCollection() {
    this.collections = []; //An array of Collection objects
    this.group = []; //A vector with a string that designates the group (e.g. 2013, 2012)
}
SuperCollection.prototype.groupCollections = function(items, groupType) {
    //Group by year, month, day, etc...
    //For example, given a timeframe of 2012-2013, items in 2012 are put in collections[1], those from 2013 are in collections[2]
}
```

Is there a better way to manage structures like this?

Comment: Has this been answered?

Answer (score 0):

I like to make things as generic/abstract as possible

```
function Collection(items)
{
    // Could/should do some checking/coercion here 
    this.items = items || [];
};

Collection.prototype.add = Collection.prototype.push = function(item)
{
    this.items.push(item);
};

Collection.prototype.remove = function() {} ....

 // etc...

// A single Group
function Group(name, items)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.items = new Collection(items);
};

// A Collection of groups
function Groups()
{
    this.groups = new Collections();
};
```

or you could extend the Groups' prototype with the Collection's prototype (a form of inheritance)
E.g (using jQuery, or any other library, or write your own)

```
function Groups()
{

};

$.extend(Groups.prototype, Collection.prototype);
```

Which leaves us with:

```
var groups = new Groups();

groups.add(new Group("2013", []));
```

All this allows you to keep your logic separate, as well as include helper methods on the Groups/Group 'classes' that are separate from your Collection 'class'